# How to navigate to a detail screen with a navigationLink containing a ZStack with some layout

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am building a recipe app, and I build it as follows:
first, I created in a separate struct, a basic view with an `Image` as background and some text on top. then I created a few horizontal `ScrollViews` where I embedded a view of those basic views.
I want, that when a user taps on one of those views, that they go to a detail screen based on their selection. To do that I embedded all the code of the view with the image and the text inside a `navigationLink`. but when I run the app in the simulator, and I press on one of the views, nothing happens.

this is the code of the view with the text and image:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: titleText)) {
            ZStack {
                Image(foodImageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.original)

                VStack {
                    Text(titleText)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "AAAAAA"))
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 189, height: 194)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .shadow(color: Color.init(hex:"000000"), radius: 7,x: 7, y: 7)
        }
```

and this is the code of the main view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private var spacing: CGFloat = 20
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("First Course")
                    .frame(height: 36)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))

                ScrollView (Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                    HStack{
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Soup", foodImageName: "Soup")
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Fish", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    }
                }.frame(height: 200)

                Text("Main Course")
                    .frame(height: 36)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))

                ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal) {
                    HStack {
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Steak", foodImageName: "Soup")
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Chicken", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    }
                }

                Text("Dessert")
                    .frame(height: 36)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))

                ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal) {
                    HStack {
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Ice cream", foodImageName: "Soup")
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Pancakes", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("Recipes")
        }
    }

}
```

does anybody have a suggestion on what I did wrong?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap every `MenuTopicView` in its separate NavigationLink and add it to your `ContentView` in order for it to work, because they all have their own individual destinations. So like this:

```
            ScrollView (Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                HStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView("Soup")) {
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Soup", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView("Fish")) {
                        MenuTopicView(titleText: "Fish", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    }
                }
            }.frame(height: 200)
```

I would suggest to make more generic Views so you don't have to repeat yourself. Something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let sections: [MenuSection]

    private var spacing: CGFloat = 20
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
                    MenuSectionView(sectionTitle: section.title, items: section.items)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Recipes")
        }
    }
}

struct MenuSectionView: View {
    let sectionTitle: String
    let items: [MenuItem]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(sectionTitle)
                .frame(height: 36)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))
            ScrollView (Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: RecipeView(recipeName: item.title)) {
                            MenuTopicView(titleText: item.title, foodImageName: item.image)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.frame(height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your main view is wrapped in a `NavigationView`, but none of the items in the `VStack` is in a `NavigationLink`. You can try this:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: titletext) {
            Text("First Course")
                .frame(height: 36)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))

            ScrollView (Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                HStack{
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Soup", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Fish", foodImageName: "Soup")
                }
            }.frame(height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

In order for `NavigationLink` to work, it must be embedded in a `NavigationView`.

Comment: Ah, I understand, even when It is not a full screen, but a sub  of a screen? @eatyourpotato ?

Comment: Right, unless that subview is already embedded in a NavigationView from another view, in which case you can just wrap it in a NavigationLink by itself. But in your code, I don't think your NavigationLink is already inside a NavigationView.

Comment: the subView is embedded in a navigationView, in another screen. ie. the subview is shown on screen via the contentView, and the contentView is embedden in a naviagtionView @eatyourpotato

Comment: I tried to embbed the (sub)view with the navigationLink inside a navigationView, but it didnt work, it even didnt display the views on the home screen

Comment: Could you show how you are embedding the NavigationLink in your NavigationView?

Comment: sure, will send it now

Comment: have sent it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

@eatyourpotato this is the code I have, it was too long for a comment, so here it is:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            NavigationLink(destination: RecipeView(recipeName: titleText)) {
                ZStack {
                    Image(foodImageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.original)

                    VStack {
                        Text(titleText)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "AAAAAA"))
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 189, height: 194)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(color: Color.init(hex:"000000"), radius: 7,x: 7, y: 7)
            }
        }
    }
```